# React useEffect return best practice

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to understand if it's against React's best-practices to use return in useEffect, to avoid some logic from being executed.
So far in documentation I only see it being used for clean-ups.

I have a candidate which wrote similar logic:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (foo === 'bar') {
   baz();
   return;
  }
  xyz();
,[foo]);
```

Ideally should be one of:

1.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (foo === 'bar') {
   baz();
  } else {
    xyz();
  }
,[foo]);
```

2. two smaller useEffects
3. logic separated from useEffect, and is conditional

However, to not have this opinion based. I am trying to find articles on this best-practice?
PS. Official React docs do NOT have this kind of approach used ANYWHERE, or mention it other than a clean-up function.

Comment: Does it work? If it does then <meh>. Your **opinion** is that it's not ok. One mans best practice is anothers terrible hack

Comment: that's why I am asking for some documented/official best practices @Liam

Comment: Additionally my main concern is that this kind of approach is NOWHERE to be found in the official react docs

Comment: `return` does just that, `return`. This is not going to break anything. React are not going to document every usage of the JS language

Comment: no, is not just return, according to official react documentation, the return of useEffect is expected to be a function, which is used for clean-up (clearIntervals etc), this seems like a big red flag, when we have a car that has an engine which heats up during driving, and instead of cooling it, we use it to melt cheese for our sandwiches.

Comment: **is expected to be a function**, no that's incorrect [*This is the **optional** cleanup mechanism for effects. Every effect **may** return a function that cleans up after it.*](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#example-using-hooks-1). There is nothing wrong with this code.

Comment: but in that example from docs you sent, it just returns a function, the return under it is the jsx @Liam

Comment: Read the document... It's all in there

Answer (score 4):

When you return *nothing* from a function (or `useEffect`) it *defaults* to returning `undefined`; similar thing happens if you just write `return`. So there is nothing wrong with this:

```
 if (foo === 'bar') {
   baz();
   return;
  }
```

So, writing `return` would be similar to just writing `useEffect` *without* `return` keyword, which is Ok.

Valid things you can return from `useEffect` are: `undefined` or a cleanup function.

Comment: Is there any article/documentation that valid return is typeof undefined and 
a function? Why not a number like 0, or 1?

Comment: @Alex Js is not a typed language. function is a first class nullable **object**. `() => undefined` is valid syntax

Comment: @Alex Try returning something else and you should get a warning or error (see console)

Comment: @Liam yes, () => undefined, is a valid syntax, but I am talking about best-practices, using vars instead of consts is a valid syntax too, but not considered as a best-practice

Comment: There is no such thing as "best practice"